# re-use pillar values in salt(-ssh)

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am currently getting familiar with salt and wonder how I could re-use the values of pillars in other places (sections) in `.sls` files.

In `buildout`, I would be able to reference a variable from another section with `${sectionname:varname}` to re-use a once defined value. This is especially handy, when dealing with directories (basedir, appdir). `buildout` example:

```
['foo']
  path = /highway/to/hell

['bar']
  path = ${foo:path}/lastexit
```

When I try to reference another variable in an `.sls` file, even if it is in the same file, I get always `None`. `salt` example:

```
foo:
  path: /highway/to/hell

bar:
  path: {{ salt['pillar.get']('foo:path') }}/lastexit
```

`salt-ssh minion1 pillar.get bar:path` results in `None/lastexit`

I have the feeling, that I'm missing something here. Could someone point out, how one does re-use values in salt `.sls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jinja to assign a value, e.g.:

```
{% set base_path = salt['pillar.get']('foo:path','/highway/to/hell') %}

foo:
  path: {{ base_path }}

bar:
  path: {{ base_path }}/lastexit
```

In this case "/highway/to/hell" is set as a default in case no value is assigned in the pillar or no pillar is found. For more info, see https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html